# Graphing in Dataframe Pandas Pyton. How to plot a line after filtering a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

So I have a pandas Dataframe with pateint id, date of visit, location, weight, and heartrate. I need to graph the line of the number of visits in one location in the Dataset over a period of 12 months with the month number on the horizontal axis.

Any other suggestions about how I may go about this?

I tried making the data into 3 data sets and then just graphing the number of visits counted from each data set but creating new columns and assigning the values wasn't working, it only worked for when I was graphing the values of all of the clinics but after splitting it into 3 dataframes, it stopped working.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XhAb.png)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of filtering a DataFrame and using the filtered results to plot a chart.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# larger dataframe example
d = {'x values':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'y values':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# apply filter
df = df[df['x values'] < 5]

# plot chart
plt.plot(df['x values'], df['y values'])
plt.show()
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

simply place your data into an ndarray and plot it with the matplotlib.pyplot or you can simply plot from a dataframe for example plt.plot(df['something'])